# RWeka wont install (mac)

Tags: java, r, macos

I seem to be having issues installing `RWeka` in R, on my mac.

I've read through a number of websites but nothing seems to work. I have Java 8 installed on my mac (I'm running OS X Sierra and I'm running R version 3.3.2).

When I attempt to install the R package I get the error:

> Warning message:
>   In install.packages("RWeka") :
>     installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status

In grey letters, several lines up it also says:

> Need at least Java version 1.7/7.0.

I'm running the latest version of Java (1.8) but it doesn't seem to sync up with RWeka for some reason. I've tried shutting down R and re-starting it, but that doesn't seem to help either.

R also throws up a pop up informing me:

> To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK.
>   Click "More Info..." to visit the Java Developer Kit download website.

If I click "Ok" it simply opens a mac website but there is nothing on there regarding a Java Developer Kit. I've used the search function on the website with no success. I've googled Java Developer Kit but can't seem to figure out what it is or how it is supposed to even work.

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Comment: The JDK is [available from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html), but I'm only about 25% confident installing it will actually solve your problem. I've [maybe temporarily] given up on Java-based R packages since updating to Sierra, which broke all of them.

Comment: Oh, bummer to hear about that with Sierra! I guess I'll need to just find a work around. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `rJava` and `RWeka` wont install in `RStudio` (`Version 1.0.136`). The following worked for me (`macOS Sierra version 10.12.6`) (found [here](https://gist.github.com/mmulvahill/ddd75eb352979cc922bae001505833cb)):

Step-1: Download and install `javaforosx.dmg` from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US)

Step-2: Next, run the command from inside RStudio:

```
install.packages("rJava", type = 'source')
install.packages("RWeka")
```